# How to access an IMAP Server using the iOS SDK

Tags: ios, frameworks, imap

Are there any classes/frameworks within the iOS SDK which can be used to easily access an IMAP server?

I do NOT what to write a new Mail app. I just need the basic IMAP functions like check for new message, download messages, etc.

So far I have found MailCore but as far as I can tell it is for MacOS and not iOS.

Thank you very much for your help!
Andrei

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [remail](http://code.google.com/p/remail-iphone/) project so you can look into it... there is no public iOS framework for dealing with IMAP as much as I know...